# Largest File in Directory

Tags: c#

We have been given an assignment where we read information from directories. I am struggling with finding the file with the largest value. I have tried this;

```
using System.IO; 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("path");
    FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

    int largestSize;

    for (largestSize = 0; largestSize < files.Length; largestSize++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(files[largestSize].Length);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But this does not work. When I say it does not work, I mean it displays files sizes of all files in the directory in a list. I am utterly confused because this is exactly what my tutor suggested. "To make a variable for largest file starting at 0 and looping through files to find largest size".

I doubt I can use or understand the Foreach loop because so far I have only learned For, do-while, while, and if and if else statements.

Comment: I think you need to spend a bit more time understanding what each statement and construct in the code is actually doing, instead of treating the code as an opaque magic spell that will perform a certain task.

Comment: Here's a play by play of what's going on in the code you've posted. You instantiate a `FolderInfo` object (which represents a folder, and exposes members that allow you to get more information about the folder and its contents). You use this instance to get an array of `FileInfo` objects, which similarly represent files. You then iterate over the array of files, using a counter named `largestSize` (this is probably where you're going wrong), and for every `FileInfo`, you write the value of the `Length` property to the console. Finally, you wait for the user to press enter.

Comment: I am a beginner, absolute beginner. This is my first Programming Language, before I barely had knowledge of VB Coding. I will go through and try to understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
long largestSize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    if (files[i].Length > largestSize)
         largestSize = files[i].Length;
}
Console.WriteLine(largestSize);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I have repaired it

Comment: @Domestos99 Thank You so much, I had used similar code before but I had it wrong because  instead of largestSize = files[i].Length; i wrote this largestSize+= files[i].Length;

Comment: @Domestos99 To display the name I tried files[largestSize].Name and files[i].Name but neither display the name of the largest file... Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @FarhaAbdul You can not use size of the file as an index and i is wrong too. I would use next valiable for index of the largest file.

Comment: @Domestos99 I know I am very slow so sorry, but I don't understand? What I understand is that using i and largestSize cannot be used as an index what I don't understand and cannot figure out is what is the next variable for largest file.

Comment: @FarhaAbdul
long largestSize = 0;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                if (files[i].Length > largestSize)
                {
                    largestSize = files[i].Length;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(largestSize);
            Console.WriteLine(files[index].Name);

Comment: @Domestos99 thank you, I was going to make a string variable not an int one, thank you for correcting me. Have a good day!

Comment: @Domestos99 :) Thank you... I will make sure I do!

Answer (score 1):

This sorts files by size descending

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles()
                       .OrderByDescending(f => f.Length)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

and will return the largest file, or null if directory contains no files.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting so many downvotes, but you might want to use `Max` instead of `OrderBy` and `FirstOrDefault`, since there's no point in sorting every file in the dir by size.

Comment: He's getting downvotes because sorting is just inappropriate when looking for an extreme.

Comment: and this is way too advanced for a beginner

Comment: @Asad: [Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns a number (file size) and never the entity (file). What the point to have  the largest file size without having its name?

Comment: @Ondrej: oh really? are we talking here about optimal performance in worst case or getting things done in the most readable and maintainable way?

Comment: @Selman22: I disagree. Writing your own beginner's version of finding a max value in array isn't a good start imo.

Comment: why not?  implementing your own algorithm is the best way to learn. this code will not give anything to OP but confusion.

Comment: Ah yes. I think the best solution here is to write out the loop explicitly (`foreach` should eliminate most of the useless code here). Alternatively, you could hack something together with `Aggregate` that still works in linear time.

Comment: @Selman22: it depends on the goal: learn programming in C# or achieve the goal. If former than yes - read books, write loops. If later - use LINQ.

Comment: @Sid: `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` returns file names, so sorting will return the longest file by its name not by its size.

Comment: Then he has something new to learn. This "oh learning stuff" is really boring. Coding like this with LINQ is absolutly normal and beginner stuff in *EVERY* Functional Programming language. There is not a single reason not to learn this stuff, also not as a beginner.

Comment: @Sid: I tend to agree! Why mess up with unreadable loops that you will skip later anyway and don't learn functional-like LINQ which is not hard to understand. Vice versa, it's easy to use and easy to read.

Comment: @SidBurn But performing extra work and increasing the code's time complexity just for the sake of saving a few keystrokes is not a path you should set a newbie down. Things should be made as convenient as reasonably possible, but not more convenient. If you really like the expressiveness of LINQ, add an enumerable extension method like `MaxBy` or something that finds the max item using the correct algorithm, and returns it. Then use *that* in your short, nice to look at code.

Comment: @abaitshchev The `DirectoryInfo` class has no static methods! So your code is wrong, but yes my correction also was not correct.

Comment: @Asad: writing readable and maintainable code is what a programmer should produce. (pre-)mature optimization isn't required here. How much will you save? 125 ms? Oh, come on!

Comment: @Asas The overall complexity of code is reduced. And is the other way around. Performance compelxity is something a beginner but also a proffesional should never care about. `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`. You never care for performance. You only optimize for performance if you have performance problems. And then you first start a Profiler. Optimizing this LINQ Loop to a full-fletched foreach loop for `performance` is just stupid.

Comment: Yes, you can wrap your loops with extension methods (try to describe this concept to a beginner) and end up with LINQ-line syntax. But what for in the first place when you can use LINQ itself?

Comment: Once Eric Lippert [answering my question asked me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258999/is-hashsett-the-fastest-container-to-look-up-in#comment2224761_2262139): why are you wondering about performance here? Is this your performance bottleneck? No? Then why then? If you care about performance go and find the real bottleneck and try to solve it. Otherwise go further, achieve the goal you're coding for.

Comment: @abatishchev This isn't premature optimization. We're not fine tuning the program here to save time, we're talking about eliminating orders of magnitude of completely useless activity. This is a case of using the right algorithm, when the entire point is to learn about how to solve problems programmatically. It is a bad idea to pull out the LINQ hammer when what you need is a screwdriver, even if LINQ is a really nice hammer.

Comment: The precedent you're setting here is: if you can't find something in the BCL that does exactly what you need, don't go out and find a library or write it yourself. Instead, hack it together in a half-assed manner from the BCL building blocks.

Comment: @SidBurn You've missed the key part of the quote: `"We should forget about **small** efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%"`.

Comment: @Asad Nope, i don't missed it. This code is not part of the critical 3%. If you have performance problems, you profile. Only when it is proven that this code is critical then you optimize it. You don't have proven anything. It is nearly impossible that this code will be critical at all. So optimizing this code beforehand, like you suggest, is premature optimization.

Comment: @SidBurn Whether this code is performance critical is something we don't know. We also don't know if it will be run in a directory with 36 files or 36 million files. Will we save 3 ms or 3 minutes by selecting the right algorithm? The memory requirements are also very different between the two. It's never premature optimization to select a linear algorithm over an n log n algorithm. Sorting in this case is premature pessimization.

Comment: @David
Here, a linear algorithm. 

`var largestFile = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles().Aggregate((acc, x) => acc.Length > x.Length ? acc : x);`

If you now you have 3 Mio entries you change it slighty to the above. If you always assume the worst-case and optimize for the worst-case. This is premature-optimization.

Comment: @David And there is nothing wrong in choosing an algorithm that is slower or not the "fastest". Also what is "fastest" can completly change depending on the data. That is also the reason why someone should pick the easiest algorithm, and only if you have proven that this algorithm is not suitable, you change the algorithm or use a faster algorithm. This is also the `KISS-Principle`. If you always try to pick the fastest algorithm directly from the start you will probably waste more time than you will ever gain.

Comment: @SidBurn Yes, the aggregate route is something I explicitly mentioned earlier, and have no problem with (except at this point it is scarcely more readable than a simple loop). You're throwing out a lot of programming advice cliches here, most of which are not applicable. I personally can't justify doing a full sort for no other reason than that it saves me a few keystrokes, just as I wouldn't justify doing string concatenation using file appends in some hypothetical language that had a nicer API for file manipulation.

Comment: @Asas i don't see any benefit in writing more code, that has likely more bugs, is harder to read/understand with absolutly no benefits at all. Doing it with LINQ either Sorting or Aggregate is simple and easy. Pick all files. Sort by size descending. Pick first file (and you have the largest size) is easy to understand and follow. I would probably pick the Aggregate, but the meaning of the Aggregate can still be a little bit obscure as Ordering. And as long as this code is fast enough, it is also okay to use it.

Comment: @Asas If you optimize beforehand like you suggest, because you *think* it could not be fast enough is just Premature optimiziation. Also just Ordering by size, or Aggregating is also an easy algorithm. So it follows KISS. If you do a foreach-loop you also would do what Aggregate do. But the real intention if the code is more hidden.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sidburn/f3e16ba40bd352316b75 Sorting 10,000 files on my PC: Ordering -> 41ms; Aggregate -> 37ms; foreach -> 35ms. Yeah nice. With an explicit foreach loop you have saved 6ms compared to the way Ordering. Yeah awesome! Completly waist of time to talk about performance here. And 10.000 files in a directory is usally what you will never see.

Comment: The simplest, most obvious algorithm in this case is one that runs in linear time and constant space, and which any programmer can easily produce with little thought and no bugs in a trivial amount of time. Using anything else is simply foolish.

Comment: @David Sentence corrected: The simplest, most obvious algorithm in any case is one that any programmer can easily produce with little thought and no bugs in a trivial amount of time.

Comment: I read through about half of the discussion. **The OP is learning how to code** — this is the *primary thought here*. As an employer, I don't want to hire (no, I don't even want to interview) half-baked developers who pull out LINQ for every trivial problem. For the OP to be successful as a developer, I believe it is **critical to learn applying proper algorithms and understanding data structures**. In other words, read the good-ol' Niclaus Wirth's book. Plus, sequence, selection, iteration paradigms — the *very basics* of common programming languages.

Comment: Alas. This is incorrect approach to hire programmers. In my opinion. People who know data structures and can write trivial algorithms for trivial tasks and can't solve your business goals won't solve your business goals despite they know data structures.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4 (or `GetFiles` in .Net 3.5) :

```
long maxSize = new DirectoryInfo("path").EnumerateFiles().Max(f => f.Length);
```

For more files, PLINQ can be used for a small speedup:

```
long maxSize = new DirectoryInfo("path").EnumerateFiles().AsParallel().Max(f => f.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test");
        FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

        long[] sort = new long[files.Length];


        for (int largestSize = 0; largestSize < files.Length; largestSize++)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int largestSize2 = 0; largestSize2 < files.Length; largestSize2++)

            {
                if (files[largestSize].Length < files[largestSize2].Length)
                {
                    index++;
                }

            }  
            sort[index] = files[largestSize].Length;

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < sort.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sort[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

i tried it simplest way i could to be uderstandable for u  first i loop throug files and make a second loop for all element and i compare between values and sorted them inside array depending teher order in compare hope that what u were looking for ofcourse that for sorting files depend on size not getting largest largest always will be sort[0]